# Configure Bullet Physics for speed

Tags: performance, bulletphysics

How to configure Bullet engine for speed, not for physics accuracy? For example, is it possible to increase friction, so that objects become stationary more quickly?

Currently, I am able to do only following speed-optimziation:

```
btContactSolverInfo& info = dynamicsWorld->getSolverInfo();
info.m_numIterations = 4;
```

Comment: It looks like your example does not match the general case in your first question. Increasing friction will not make the physics engine faster/slower at the expense of less/more accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

aside from changing number of iterations in the solver you can:

- Use a larger step time. 1/100 is two times faster (computationally) than 1/200 and you will get lesser accuracy. you should be careful about stability though.
- Use simpler collision shapes. You may use a box shape instead of convex shapes.(Or divide convex shapes into simpler objects) Even you can use AABBs or cylinders(in z direction only) for collision shapes(this is what games was doing 10 years ago i guess)